# Improve the JOINs between Facttable and dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, dimensions, fact-table

I'm working on SSMS 2012.

I've created a Facttable along with its dimensions, both connected with a 
ParentID relationship. I've created Views displaying the Facttable and the dimensions in a more user-friendly way (simply unpivoting things). Everything work flawless when I use LEFT OUTER JOIN to get information from those views.

The thing is in some of my dimensions, I have a n-to-1 relationship with respect to my Facttable. For example, I've stored general information about a company in my Facttable and the daily value of its stock in the dimension.

The "problem" is when I do the LEFT OUTER JOIN of the views I have a lot of redundant information on the left part of the table (corresponding to the general information about the company).

To give you an idea:

```
   NAME      CITY      DATE           STOCK_PRICE
   Alpha     Tokyo     05/01/2017        2.2
   Alpha     Tokyo     04/01/2017        2.3
   Alpha     Tokyo     03/01/2017        2.1
   Alpha     Tokyo     02/01/2017        2.0
   Alpha     Tokyo     01/01/2017        2.4
```

I know that NULLs are handled in a way more efficient way than "actual" values.
The idea would be to achieve something like that.

```
   NAME      CITY      DATE           STOCK_PRICE
   Alpha     Tokyo     05/01/2017        2.2
   NULL      NULL      04/01/2017        2.3
   NULL      NULL      03/01/2017        2.1
   NULL      NULL      02/01/2017        2.0
   NULL      NULL      01/01/2017        2.4
```

In the best case, the idea would be doable for multiple "redundant" info from the Facttable and different dimensions (if different prices per day for the same company exist, the same date would just appear once and then would be NULL)

Here is my idea, but feel free to give your opinion on the matter. The core is really to avoid my big 1-to-n relationships to make it hard for my computer.

Comment: Really, what you seem to be asking is "how can I get only the most recent row from my companies table" - a question that has been asked many times (approximately 73,000 it seems).. Google for `site:stackoverflow.com most recent row`

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are using and the results that you want.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you are actually asking. It seems you are worried that with the strings getting repeated over and over this may cause problems with available memory on your computer. But you wouldn't select all companies with all their data anyway. So we are not talking of billions of rows, but maybe some hundreds or thousands. And this is certainly no problem. So I'd say brush your worries away :-)

Comment: Please give a more specific example.  It sounds as though your design of either (or both) your fact table or dimension table has an issue.  Without being able to see the structures involved, we can't tell.  You may also benefit from reading about Minimal Complete Verifiable Examples.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This, `For example, I've stored general information about a company in my Facttable and the daily value of its stock in the dimension`, sounds backwards.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That's what I needed to hear I guess. Thanks :)

Comment: @MatBailie I'll take a look at it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this means:

> I know that NULL's are handled in a way more efficient way than "actual" values. The idea would be to achieve something like that.

This is not something that I "know".

If you only want values on the most recent row, then you can do so using `row_number()`.  I don't recommend this, but the SQL looks like:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select (case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then city end) as city,
       date, stock_price
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, city order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by name, city, seqnum;
```

The reason I do not recommend this is that SQL result sets are normally unordered.  By replacing values, you are imposing an order on the result set.  I've adjusted the query to have an explicit `order by`, so the rows are as you would expect.